# does not name a type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resolve circular dependencies in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c)
>   [What is forward declaration in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926105/what-is-forward-declaration-in-c)

I have two classes A and B. I need to have a field in each which is a pointer to an object of the other class. I get "does not name a type" since the definition of the class is yet to appear. For example:

```
class A{
   B* b;
}
class B{
   A* a;
}
```

gets me "B "does not name a type" at the second line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use forward declarations:

```
class B;

class A {
  B* b;
};

class B {
  A* a;
};
```

This way you're telling the compiler that `B` is going to be declared later on and that it should not worry. See this for more info: [Forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration)

Answer (score 1):

Forward declarations is key to you question , here is the link

[What is forward declaration in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926105/what-is-forward-declaration-in-c)