# A newbie and the timer module that doesn't compile

Tags: c++, timer, arduino

I'm totally new to C/C++. I've done some higher languages like Java and C# but that's something else I must say. I'm trying to build a timer module for the Arduino so that I can easily queue work that has to be executed after a certain amount of time without the use of `delay()`. I would like to create it as intuitively as possible so that I can easily re-use it.

So far I've tried a lot of different approaches. What I did is mostly read tutorials on how to achieve a certain thing in C/C++ and created my little project out of that.

Main .ino file:

```
#include "Timer.h"

Timer timer;

void setup()
{
    // Init the timer
    timer.init();

    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

    // Define the state
    int state = 1;

    // Create the action
    TimerAction action;
    action.create(1000, &timerElapsed, 1 -1);
    action.state = &state;
}

void loop()
{
    timer.run();
}

void timerElapsed(TimerAction action) {
    int *state = (int*)action.state;
    if (state == 0) {
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        *state = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);
        *state = 0;
    }
}
```

It's very simple. I'm trying to blink the onboard led as a proof of concept.

This is the `Timer.h` file:

```
#ifndef _TIMER_h
#define _TIMER_h

#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
    #include "arduino.h"
#else
    #include "WProgram.h"
#endif

struct Timer {
    TimerAction* actions;
    uint8_t size;

    void init();
    void queue(TimerAction action);
    void dequeue(TimerAction action);
    void dequeueIdx(int idx);
    void run();
};

struct TimerAction {
    // Sets whether to repeat the action
    uint8_t repetitive;
    // Sets how many times to repeat the action, -1 for infinite
    // Will only be used when repetitive == 1
    long finite;

    void (*callback)(TimerAction sender);
    void *state;

    unsigned long last;
    unsigned long interval;

    void create(long interval, void(*callback)(TimerAction sender), uint8_t repetitive = 0U, long finite = -1L);
};

#endif
```

This is the `Timer.ino` file:

```
#include "Timer.h"

void Timer::init() {
    size = 0;
    actions = new TimerAction[10];
}

void Timer::queue(TimerAction action) {
    action.last = millis();
    actions[size - 1] = action;

    size++;
}

void Timer::dequeue(TimerAction action) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (&(actions[i]) == &action) {
            memmove(actions + i, actions + i + 1, (size - (i + 1)) * sizeof(TimerAction));
            break;
        }
}

void Timer::dequeueIdx(int idx) {
    memmove(actions + idx, actions + idx + 1, (size - (idx + 1)) * sizeof(TimerAction));
}

void Timer::run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if ((actions[i].last + actions[i].interval) >= millis()) {
            TimerAction action = actions[i];
            action.callback(action);
            if (action.repetitive == 1) {
                if (action.finite > 0)
                    action.finite--;
                else
                    if (action.finite == 0)
                        dequeueIdx(i);
            }
            else
                dequeueIdx(i);
        }
}

void TimerAction::create(long _interval, void(*_callback)(TimerAction sender),
                         uint8_t _repetitive = 0U, long _finite = -1L) {
    interval = _interval;
    callback = _callback;
    repetitive = _repetitive;
    finite = _finite;
}
```

These are the errors the compiler spewed out:

```
Arduino: 1.6.1 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino Uno"

In file included from Stoplicht.ino:1:0:

Timer.h:13:2: error: 'TimerAction' does not name a type

  TimerAction* actions;

  ^

Timer.h:17:13: error: 'TimerAction' has not been declared

  void queue(TimerAction action);

             ^

Timer.h:18:15: error: 'TimerAction' has not been declared

  void dequeue(TimerAction action);

               ^

Timer.ino: In member function 'void Timer::init()':

Timer.ino:5:2: error: 'actions' was not declared in this scope

Timer.ino: At global scope:

Timer.ino:8:6: error: prototype for 'void Timer::queue(TimerAction)' does not match any in class 'Timer'

In file included from Stoplicht.ino:1:0:

Timer.h:17:7: error: candidate is: void Timer::queue(int)

  void queue(TimerAction action);

       ^

Timer.ino:15:6: error: prototype for 'void Timer::dequeue(TimerAction)' does not match any in class 'Timer'

In file included from Stoplicht.ino:1:0:

Timer.h:18:7: error: candidate is: void Timer::dequeue(int)

  void dequeue(TimerAction action);

       ^

Timer.ino: In member function 'void Timer::dequeueIdx(int)':

Timer.ino:24:10: error: 'actions' was not declared in this scope

Timer.ino: In member function 'void Timer::run()':

Timer.ino:29:8: error: 'actions' was not declared in this scope

Timer.ino: At global scope:

Timer.ino:45:52: error: default argument given for parameter 3 of 'void TimerAction::create(long int, void (*)(TimerAction), uint8_t, long int)' [-fpermissive]

In file included from Stoplicht.ino:1:0:

Timer.h:36:7: error: after previous specification in 'void TimerAction::create(long int, void (*)(TimerAction), uint8_t, long int)' [-fpermissive]

  void create(long interval, void(*callback)(TimerAction sender), uint8_t repetitive = 0U, long finite = -1L);

       ^

Timer.ino:45:52: error: default argument given for parameter 4 of 'void TimerAction::create(long int, void (*)(TimerAction), uint8_t, long int)' [-fpermissive]

In file included from Stoplicht.ino:1:0:

Timer.h:36:7: error: after previous specification in 'void TimerAction::create(long int, void (*)(TimerAction), uint8_t, long int)' [-fpermissive]

  void create(long interval, void(*callback)(TimerAction sender), uint8_t repetitive = 0U, long finite = -1L);

       ^
```

Let me explain why I'm using `Array` over a `std::vector`. My chain of thought was this: the Arduino is quite weak and `actions` is going to be accessed a lot. So I thought it's a bit more work to implement it initially but it will make sure the timer doesn't use too much of the Arduino's resources.

I've tried a lot of things but I don't really understand where the problem lies. So that's why I'm asking an expert to look at my code and maybe put me on the right track.

Comment: You have to forward declare `struct TimerAction;` before using it in the `Timer` class declaration.

Comment: OT: Your include guard is illegal. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ omg answers in comments staaaahppppppp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Timer.h you have:

```
TimerAction* actions;
```

At the point in time that the compiler sees that line of code it has not seen what a `TimerAction` is.  As such it does not know what the type is and is giving you an error.  What you need to do is [forward declare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926105/what-is-forward-declaration-in-c) `TimerAction` before `Timer` so the compiler knows what it is doing.

```
#ifndef _TIMER_h
#define _TIMER_h

#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
    #include "arduino.h"
#else
    #include "WProgram.h"
#endif

struct TimerAction;

struct Timer {
//...
```