# C++ make two structs reference each other in there functions

Tags: c++, struct

I have two structs "pointInt" and "pointFloat" and I want to "cast" them into each other with a ".toInt()" and ".toFloat()" function

```cpp
struct pointInt {
    int x;
    int y;

    pointFloat toFloat()
    {
        return {(float)x, (float)y};
    }
};
```

```cpp
struct pointFloat {
    float x;
    float y;

    pointInt toInt()
    {
        return {(int)x, (int)y};
    }
};
```

But then I get an error

```
In file included from src/include/physics.cpp:2:
src/include/physics.h:66:5: error: 'pointFloat' does not name a type; did you mean 'pointInt'?
```

Is there a way around this or is there a better way to convert between these two structs?

I tried to use a forward declaration but that also doesn't work. I just get an error saying that the type of 'struct pointFloat' is incomplete.

I also tried to define just the function later, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714091/having-two-structs-refer-to-each-others-variables-in-c)

```cpp
struct pointInt {
    int x;
    int y;

    pointFloat toFloat();
};

struct pointFloat {
    float x;
    float y;

    pointInt toInt();
};

pointFloat pointInt::toFloat()
{
    return {(float)x, (float)y};
}

pointInt pointFloat::toInt()
{
    return {(int)x, (int)y};
}
```

But now I get a multiple definitions error.

Comment: Your last snippet is almost okay, all it needs is that you define the functions as *inline*. Otherwise each [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) where the header file is included will have the definition of those function, and non-inline member functions can only be defined (implemented) once.

Comment: On a different note, please don't do C-style casts (explicit type-conversions). Whenever you feel the need to do such a cast you should almost always consider it as doing something wrong. First of all, do you really *need* those casts? C++ have some nice implicit conversions that might be working here. And if an explicit conversion is needed use `static_cast` instead.

Comment: Also, unless you have *very* specific requirements, don't use `float` for floating-point values and variables. Use `double`.

Comment: And lastly, what is your actual assignment? What is the underlying and actual problem that needs to be solved by two almost the same structures? Can't it be solved using only one single structure?

Comment: TLDR: move the function definitions to a cpp file, or mark them inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions cannot be inlined within both `struct` definitions, since defining each function requires the corresponding `struct` to be defined.   Essentially, to define a function that returns a `struct` type by value, the compiler must see the complete *definition* of `struct` being returned *before* the function is defined.

The problems you're seeing in your code are due to a circular dependency, in which both `struct` definitions (with their inlined definition of a member function returning the other) mutually rely on the other being defined.

To break that circular dependency, use a forward declaration.   If you define the two `struct`s in different header files, you might do something like

**Option 1**  Separate header for each `struct` type

```
// header that defines pointInt
 
struct pointFloat;

struct pointInt {  
    int x;
    int y;

    pointFloat toFloat() const;
};
```

and

```
// header that defines pointFloat
 
struct pointInt;

struct pointFloat {  
    float x;
    float y;

    pointInt toFloat() const;
};
```

Then, define the member functions (which requires both `struct`s to be defined) in a separate source file.  Note that it is not possible to inline the function definition within either header (doing so will reintroduce another circular dependency)

```
#include "pointint.h"
#include "pointfloat.h"

//  defining the functions below requires both structs to be defined

pointFloat pointInt::toFloat() const
{
    return {float(x), float(y)};
   // static_cast<float>(x), static_cast<float>(y) is often considered preferable

}

pointInt pointFloat::toInt() const
{
    return {int(x), int(y)};
}
```

It also means that, if you want to call either of your two member functions, both headers must be included.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pointint.h"
#include "pointdouble.h"

int main()
{
    pointInt a{42,43};
    std::cout << a.toFloat().x << '\n';
}
```

Some people don't like having to `#include` two headers in order to use one `struct`.   Which brings us to .....

**Option 2**  Define both `struct` types in a single header

An alternative, if you want both `struct` definitions in one header (which does away with the need to include two headers to call `pointFloat::toInt()` or `pointInt::toFloat()`).

```
struct pointFloat;   // needed before defining pointInt

struct pointInt {  
    int x;
    int y;

    pointFloat toFloat() const;
};

// no forward declaration of pointFloat needed since we have defined it

struct pointFloat {  
    float x;
    float y;

    pointInt toFloat() const;
};

//    both function definitions require both structs to be previously defined as above

inline pointFloat pointInt::toFloat() const
{
    return {float(x), float(y)};
}

inline pointInt pointFloat::toInt() const
{
    return {int(x), int(y)};
}
```

The inlining of function definitions within that header is *optional*.  It is also possible to remove the function definitions from the header, and define them in a separate source file (which still must `#include` the header).

**Points to note in both options**

- The examples above omit include guards from the headers.   You can read up separately on why include guards are *highly advisable* in headers.
- I've rewritten to omit C-style casts, and `const` qualified your conversion functions (as, for example, `a_pointint.toFloat()` would not normally be expected to change state of `a_pointint`).

Comment: You can have `"pointint.h"` include `"pointfloat.h"` and vice-versa with guards instead of requiring including both to use either

Comment: @Caleth   Yes, indeed.    With a bit of additional reading up on include guards (what they offer as well as their limitations) the OP will be able to work from what's here to the solution you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use template of C++.
Below is the tested sample.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

template<typename T>
struct Point {
  T x;
  T y;

  template<typename F>
  Point<F> To() {
    return {static_cast<F>(x), static_cast<F>(y)};
  }
};

void convert_int_to_float() {
  Point<int> int_point;
  int_point.x = 8;
  int_point.y = 2;
  printf("ip x: %d    y: %d \n", int_point.x, int_point.y);

  Point<float> float_point = int_point.To<float>();
  printf("fp x: %.1f  y: %.1f \n", float_point.x, float_point.y);
}

void convert_float_to_int() {
  Point<float> float_point;
  float_point.x = 2.3;
  float_point.y = 6.8;
  printf("fp x: %.1f  y: %.1f \n", float_point.x, float_point.y);

  Point<int> int_point = float_point.To<int>();
  printf("ip x: %d    y: %d \n", int_point.x, int_point.y);
}

int main() {
  convert_int_to_float();
  printf("----------------------\n");
  convert_float_to_int();

  return 0;
}
```

Build commend.

```bash
$ g++ code.cc --std=c++11
```

The output.

```bash
ip x: 8    y: 2
fp x: 8.0  y: 2.0
----------------------
fp x: 2.3  y: 6.8
ip x: 2    y: 6
```

However, I have just focused on your example usage.
This Point template is not proper for a large project because no exceptional cases are considered.