# What is a forward declaration

Tags: c++, class, include

I don't understand what the line with the arrow is doing exactly. Is it including that class in this class?

```
#ifndef LINEEDIT_H
#define LINEEDIT_H

#include <QLineEdit>

class QToolButton; <--------------------------------------

class EnchancedLineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    EnchancedLineEdit(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~EnchancedLineEdit();

protected:
  void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *);

private:
    QToolButton *clearBtn;

private slots:
    void updateCloseButton(const QString &text);
};

#endif // LINEEDIT_H
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926105/what-is-forward-declaration-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a **forward declaration** of the class `QToolButton` (if you google *forward declaration c++* you will find plenty of good search results regarding this topic)

This allows the usage of the class `QToolButton` for pointers and references, as long the members of `QToolButton` are not accessed in that particular Header file.

The purpose of forward declarations is to speed up compilation. If you dont use forward declarations, you would need to include the Header file of `QToolButton`.
This would mean, that every Source file which inclues the Header file of `EnhancedLineEdit` also indirectly includes the Header file of `QToolButton`, even if that class is not used in the Source file itself, which will slow down the compilation process.

So only the source file of `EnhancedLineEdit` will need to include `<QToolButton>`. Source files which include the header file of `EnhancedLineEdit` wont need to do so, unless they want to make direct use of the class `QToolButton` themselves. Otherwise the forward declaration is sufficient to allow the usage of pointers to `QToolButton` in the header file of `EnhancedLineEdit`.

Comment: So is it kind of like a function prototype?

Comment: @rample: yes the concept is comparable. A function prototype is basically a forward declaration of a function.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
class QToolButton;
```

declares class `QToolButton` in the current (it seems global) namespace without definition of the class itself. That is this declaration introduces type `class QToolButton`in the scope. This class is used in the definition of class `EnchancedLineEdit`

```
private:
    QToolButton *clearBtn;
```

In fact it is enough to have line

```
private:
    class QToolButton *clearBtn;
    ^^^^^
```

because it also declares class `QToolButton` in the current namespace.

These specifications

```
class QToolButton;
```

and

```
class QToolButton
```

that might be used in this declaration `class QToolButton *clearBtn;` are called elaborated type names.

In the code snippet you showed the data member declaration

```
QToolButton *clearBtn;
```

does not require that type `QToolButton` would be complete until you will access members of `class QToolButton`.