# 'B::operator A' uses undefined class 'A'

Tags: c++, oop

I have found the following example in one of my C++ courses. When I try to compile it I get the following error:

```
'B::operator A' uses undefined class 'A'
```

Why does it say that class A is undefined?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A;
class B
{
    int x;
public: B(int i = 107) { x = i; }
        operator A();
};
B::operator A() { return x; }

class A
{
    int x;
public: A(int i = 6) { x = i; }
        int get_x() { return x; }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    A a = b;
    cout << a.get_x();
    system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: You can't use that with a forward declaration. Declaration of `A` needs to go before declaration of `B` in this case. Only pointers or references are allowed in your case.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler needs to know what A is here:

```
B::operator A() { return x; }
```

But you only have a forward declaration.  You need to move the declaration of class `A` above `B`

You are only allowed to use pointers to or references of incomplete types which is what have when you [forward declare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926105/what-is-forward-declaration-in-c) a type

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare A above B, so that the definition of A is visible to B.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    int x;
public: A(int i = 6) { x = i; }
        int get_x() { return x; }
};


class B
{
    int x;
public: B(int i = 107) { x = i; }
        operator A();
};
B::operator A() { return x; }

int main()
{
    B b;
    A a = b;
    cout << a.get_x();
}
```

This should work.